# How to redirect to different domains based on if there is any text after .com/?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, rewrite

I have some basic competency here, I can do one of these or the other, but cannot figure out how to do both:

If a user goes to www.example.com/anydatahere, I need to pass the anydatahere to a purl script. I have the code for that:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/purl_handler_blahblahblah&purl=$1 [R=302,NC]
```

But if they ask to go only to www.example.com, I need it to go to another domain entirely:

```
RewriteRule / http://www.example.net/someplaceelse
```

I can do one or the other in the vhost, but I don't know how to make both happen without one overriding the other.

Thanks! First and long!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to replace ^/(.*) by ^/(.+)

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+) http://www.example.com/purl_handler_blahblahblah&purl=$1 [R=302,NC]
```

- `*` mean Between zero and unlimited times
- `+` mean Between one and unlimited times

a good site to test your regexp: https://regex101.com